# Set env. variable in ansible apt module

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I'm using the ansible `apt` module to install packages on Ubuntu hosts:

```
---
-name: Install htop
  apt: name=htop state=present
```

I now want to install `sudo-ldap`, but following what I did above doesn't work:

```
---
-name: Install sudo-ldap
  apt: name=sudo-ldap state=present
```

To install `sudo-ldap` require that `export SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=yes` be set beforehand. If I were to do this on the commandline I'd do the following:

```
SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=yes apt-get install -y sudo-ldap
```

In fact, I've used this in my ansible task:

```
---
- name: Install sudo-ldap
  shell: SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=yes apt-get install -y sudo-ldap
  args:
    creates: "/etc/sudo-ldap.conf"
```

But there must be a better way to set this environmental variable so that I can use the `apt` module directly, rather than going to the shell?

Answer (score 7):

I know it is very old, but `SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE: yes` will not work. We can see here that `yes` becomes `True`:

```
<192.168.33.11> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o     StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o     'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/anyserver/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/mrbits/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt 192.168.33.11 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-vmofyrkeoiwkculfgovhifhhoylkbfrj; **SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=True** /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487325724.54-173290784938544/apt.py; rm -rf "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1487325724.54-173290784938544/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
```

apt is expecting a value `"yes"` on `SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE`, so the correct way is:

```
---
- name: Install sudo-ldap
  apt: name=sudo-ldap state=present
  environment:
    SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE: "yes"
```

Just my 2 cents.

CheerS

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your argument about `yes` becoming `True`. Aren't `yes` and `True` supposed to mean the same thing?

Comment: @Sasha, I had the same issue as above and using the quotes did resolve the issue. To Ansible `yes` and `True` are the same thing, but to the external code that is being called by Ansible, whether it be an install program and some other program called from shell, it's up to the external program how it wants to handle `yes` and `True`. If the external program is expecting `yes`, Ansible needs to set the variable to `yes`. Without the quotes Ansible will set the variable to `True`.

Answer (score 5):

You can [set env vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html) on every task like this:

```
---
- name: Install sudo-ldap
  apt: name=sudo-ldap state=present
  environment:
    SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE: yes
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm almost sure I'd tried this unsuccessfully. I'll have to try this again with a new VM as I have installed `sudo-ldap` using ansible's `shell` module. It may take a little while until I get around to this.